# spark scala data cleansing

Tags: scala, validation, apache-spark

When developing a Spark job, I always get the same issues of data cleansing. Please can you give me some clues to implement this kind of data cleansing ?

The input can be a CSV/kafka/text containing string fields, integer fields and timestamp fields. I would like to remove all the lines that aren't compliant with the data model. Sometimes I get IP instead of integer, sometimes the timestamp can't be cast to timestamp because in the wrong format...
Additionally I would like to not kill performance of the job manipulating lots of java objects and scala complex structures, and be able to put business rules.

Imagine a dataset with this model

```
case class Flow(a: String, b: Int, c: Timestamp)
```

A very simple version would be

```
val file= sc.textFile(....).split(",").filter{l=>
    l.length>x
    l(1) forall Character.isDigit
    l(2) // ???? how to match date format without costly regexp ????
}
```

Do you have any other suggestions ? using more complex solutions like Scalaz with monads or Play framework to do it ?
What would be the difference regarding performance ?

I have also looked at the spark csv parser included in 2.x but it's just a brutal try/catch/logging on type casting...

Comment: What does your `csv` look like exactly? Have you tried [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)?

Comment: Yes I have tried, it's an option, but it only tests number of fields and casting compliancy. Addtionally it doesn't keep rejected events. It would also be good to apply to all kind of source and not onyl csv and json...